# Flutter application showing Home screen after resuming

Tags: android, flutter

I am developing a flutter application. Inside app, a screen contain Forms that is to be filled by user. But while filling the fields, if the app minimized and opened after a minute (approximately), I am not able to see the same screen. Instead app showing homescreen and I am losing the data filled up to then. Is there any solution to make app remembers the screen before pausing and showing same screen without loosing data on resume?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/saving-states):

> In this scenario, your app is placed in the background the system does its best to keep your app process in memory. However, the system may destroy the application process while the user is away interacting with other apps. In such a case, the activity instance is destroyed, along with any state stored in it. When the user relaunches the app, the activity is unexpectedly in a clean state. To learn more about process death, see [Processes and Application Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/process-lifecycle).

Therefore the most "safe" way would be to store your app state in a JSON file and restore it from the JSON file on start of the app.
If the app is gracefully stopped you persist the state in the JSON file or delete the JSON file if no state should be stored.

Comment: if device system may destroying the application process, how other applications maintaining their screens and the data filled and even cursor pointers too.. could you please suggest any alternative solutions to show the same screen...?

Comment: As I wrote, you can implement your own state management via local storage